# Keeping the last value

Tags: javascript, numbers

what do I have to change to this code, so that it doesn't take "balls" with the value of 10 every time? More precisely, "balls" to keep their last value. Thank you in advance!

```js
let balls = 10;
let randomB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
if (randomB % 2 == 0) {
  balls++;
} else {
  balls -= 2;
}
console.log(balls)
```

Comment: You can store the last value into a cookie or localstorage. When the scripts starts, check and read stored value first. Seach here at [so] and you will find lots of post how the suggested ways works,

Answer (score 0):

1. For the requirement to repeat a code, you should wrap it in a function.

Documentation [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions):

> Functions are one of the fundamental building blocks in JavaScript. A function in JavaScript is... a set of statements that performs a task or calculates a value...

2. For the requirement to use a value in a function from the last run of the function, you should use a variable that relies in a scope external relational to the function.

Documentation [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope):

> The current context of execution... The context in which values and expressions are "visible" or can be referenced... Scopes can also be layered in a hierarchy...

```js
class Game {
  constructor(balls) {
    this.balls = balls;
  }
  step() {
    let randomB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    if (randomB % 2 == 0) {
      this.balls++;
    } else {
      this.balls -= 2;
    }
    return this.balls;
  }
}
const game = new Game(10);
do {
  stepResult = game.step();
  console.log(stepResult);
} while (stepResult != 0);
```

So:

1. The function we made is actually a method, named `step`.
2. The scope external related to the function (method) is it's class.